# jasmine.createSpy is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, chai, jasmine-node

I wrote the below test. But when I run it I'm getting an error saying jasmine.createSpy is not a function.

```
    import MyNode, {MqttOptions, IMessageReceivedCallBack, MyTopic, MyDataType,MyMessage} from '../../src/main/MyNode';
    import {expect} from 'chai';
    var mqtt: any = require('mqtt');
    var jasmine = require('jasmine');

    describe('MyNode Test Suite',() => {
      let myNode: MyNode;
      let mqttOptions: MqttOptions;
      let messageReceivedCallBack: IMessageReceivedCallBack;

      let willMessage = {
        topic: 'WillMessage',
        payload: 'This is the last will message',
        qos: 2,
        retain: 'true'
      };
      mqttOptions = {
        clientId: '100',
        protocolId: 'MQTT',
        protocolVersion: 4,
        keepAlive: 1000,
        clean: false,
        reconnectPeriod: '1000',
        will: willMessage
      };

      messageReceivedCallBack = {
        onMessageReceived(message: MyMessage) {
          console.log('Message was received :D ' + message.payload);
        }
      };

      it('Should call the connect method when constructor is called', () => {
        mqtt.connect = jasmine.createSpy('beforeeachthing');
        myNode = new MyNode('tcp://localhost:1883', mqttOptions, messageReceivedCallBack);
        jasmine.expect(mqtt.connect).to.have.been.called;
      });

    });
```

what is wrong here? I am new to this. Please advice.

Comment: Try removing this line `var jasmine = require('jasmine');`

Comment: Then how will I access the variable jasmine? I need to call createSpy on it right? without having this line how can I do that?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you handle your resources. I have jasmine installed as `node` module and the compiler recognizes it directly. I think your problem is that `require('jasmine')` isn't returning what you expect and therefore createSpy is not a function

Comment: Then it says it cannot find jasmine. Actually I'm using this generator https://github.com/yohangz/generator-typescript-npm-bower